# change a list to to column and row in txt file

Tags: python, text-files

[a sample file here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pTUn-agl1m1webCkTow6ZOXfZZrahKsq/view?usp=sharing) I have a really heavy text file around 4GB of containing such information. how to change the following format with python to be fast as well

Edited:
The problem is that inside the text file there are different data in the same format which I am not interested to change their format and move them to a new file (just want to skip them)

Note: this file is a sample of the big file data, in original file they a lot of each bunch.

```
domain:         x.x.x.x.in-addr.arpa
descr:          IP xxx SA
admin-c:        DUMY-RIPE
tech-c:         DUMY-RIPE
```

to

```
domain,descr,admin-c,tech-c
x.x.x.in-addr.arpa,IP xxx SA,DUMY-RIPE,DUMY-RIPE
```

Comment: Does it fit in memory? What have you tried? What is the expected output file format?

Comment: @roganjosh it is a 4 to 5 GB file and I have 8GB memory, but maybe better not to load all in memory at once, don't know, the output format can be csv or text file

Comment: Then you really should have these details in your question. You can [edit] them in.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

string = """
domain:         x.x.x.x.in-addr.arpa
descr:          IP xxx SA
admin-c:        DUMY-RIPE
tech-c:         DUMY-RIPE
"""

vals = re.findall("(.*): *(.*)", string)
k = [i[0] for i in vals]
v = [i[1] for i in vals]

out = ",".join(k) + '\n' + ",".join(v)
print(out)
```

Output:

```
domain,descr,admin-c,tech-c
x.x.x.x.in-addr.arpa,IP xxx SA,DUMY-RIPE,DUMY-RIPE
```

Explanation:

1. A regex sorts through your string to find the appropriate key/value pairs in the string.
2. We pull apart the findings into two separate lists, one containing the first column's values, and one containing the second column's values.
3. We use some `join` magic to put the output into your preferred format (which is actually called CSV, if you want to research it more), and print the result.

If you're looking to parse this in the end, take a look at the Python [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html) module for some handy tools.

---

**Edit 1**

Because I love compressed code ;), here's some smaller versions of the above code:

```
import re

string = """
domain:         x.x.x.x.in-addr.arpa
descr:          IP xxx SA
admin-c:        DUMY-RIPE
tech-c:         DUMY-RIPE
"""

vals = re.findall("(.*): *(.*)", string)
out = ",".join([i[0] for i in vals]) + '\n' + ",".join([i[1] for i in vals]
)
print(out)
```

And even a one-liner (not counting the `print` or `string` definition):

```
import re

string = """
domain:         x.x.x.x.in-addr.arpa
descr:          IP xxx SA
admin-c:        DUMY-RIPE
tech-c:         DUMY-RIPE
"""

out = ",".join([i[0] for i in re.findall("(.*): *(.*)", string)]) + '\n' + ",".join([i[1] for i in re.findall("(.*): *(.*)", string)]
)
print(out)
```

Note: the one-liner, while fancy and compact-looking, may compromise speed because it uses `re.findall` twice. For fastest performance, I would recommend the second solution.

Comment: Presumably the *domain:*, etc., keys are being repeated. If so this will not produce csv-like output. It will make two lines, one with all keys and one with all values in it. That will be a very useless 4GB file.

Comment: @connectyourcharger thanks for good explanation, but it doesn't fit to string as you made on the first as such  pairs is full in text file around 4GB.
I think should be read from file and write in another file in the output format

Comment: @FerdowsShahryar Missed the part about 4GB file (was that in the question?). I will edit in a second.

Comment: @FerdowsShahryar Could you provide a larger snippet of the file? I'll assume you know basic Python, so you could just write the contents to a file instead of printing if you want.

Comment: I definitely recommend using the `str` type's methods like `split()` and `strip()` over `re` here. The full regex parser isn't necessary for the particular transformations that are being done.

Answer (score 0):

This could be done with a shell pipeline instead of Python.

I've assumed all the records have the same four-line format and that there are no newlines between them. This solution could be modified for other cases as well.

I used this input file "test.txt":

```
domain:         x.x.x.x.in-addr.arpa
descr:          IP xxx SA
admin-c:        DUMY-RIPE
tech-c:         DUMY-RIPE
domain:         x.x.x.x.in-addr.arpa
descr:          IP xxx SA
admin-c:        DUMY-RIPE
tech-c:         DUMY-RIPE
```

And the following commands:

```
cut -f2 -d : test.txt | sed -e 's/^ *//' -e 's/$/,/' | gxargs -d '\n' -n 4 | sed -s 's/, /,/g' -e 's/,$//' > out.txt
```

For this output "out.txt":

```
x.x.x.x.in-addr.arpa,IP xxx SA,DUMY-RIPE,DUMY-RIPE
x.x.x.x.in-addr.arpa,IP xxx SA,DUMY-RIPE,DUMY-RIPE
```

It's a little janky but it should get the job done.

- `cut`: `-f2` selects the second field, `-d :` delimited by a colon
- 1st `sed`: the first `-e` `s`ubstitutes from the beginning (`^`) of the line followed by all spaces (`*`) with nothing (the lack of contents between the final two slashes (`//`); this removes the leading whitespace left by `cut`. The second `-e`  `s`ubstitutes the end (`$`) of the line with a `,` to prepare for the next step
- `xargs` (must use GNU `xargs`, hence the `g` prefix on my Mac): `-d`elimited by newlines (`'\n'`) collects each set of 4 lines (`-n 4`) and puts them on one line. This is a slightly weird use of `xargs` but it's perfect here
- 2nd `sed`: `s`ubstitutes a `,` (comma followed by space) with a `,` (no space), `g`lobally (multiple times per line). Then, `s`ubstitutes the extra trailing comma `,$` with nothing (`//`) to remove it
- `> out.txt` saves the output of the last command to `out.txt`. (**WARNING**: this will overwrite `out.txt` if it exists)

You can either manually add the header line or combine this with `cat` to get your desired final format.

If you only have to do this once or a few times, this should be more than fast enough.

Comment: And you could do this with a system call in Python, if you needed to do it programatically.

Comment: @scott the real file is 12 row and then seprate by some space line, so they are not same size always

Comment: @FerdowsShahryar if it's always 12 rows with the field names in the same order, you can delete the blank lines with `sed -e /^$/d'` and change to `xargs -n 12 ...`. If they're not always in the same order, I'd probably chose a Python solution before I got into using `sort` on subsets of a file.

Comment: @ScottColby it stays 12 but the problem is that in between there are other similar data that need to be skiped, that's why I stayed with python soluation

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function you may find useful in a Python solution.

Given an iterable of lines (like an open file would give you), this generator yields a list of each group of lines separated by white space. For example, this input:

```
abc
def

aaa
bbb
ccc
```

you would get the lists `['abc', 'def']` and `['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']`. The function should be robust to multiple newlines and other white space.

```
def group_by_newlines(lines):
    out = []
    for line in lines:
        cleaned = line.strip()
        if cleaned:  # true if there was non-whitespace on the line
            out.append(cleaned)
        else:
            if out:  # something has been added to out already
                yield out
                out = []  # prepare for the next set of output
            else:  # we're in a group of newlines, so move on to the next line
                continue  # not strictly necessary, you could just fall off the `if` branch

    if out:
        yield out  # yield the final set of lines
```

Once you have lists of groups of lines, you can do whatever logic you need to find the data you want to process and use a combination of `split(':')`, `strip()` and equality testing to parse the data into the comma-separated lines you want.

It's generally better to avoid regexes when string methods can do the job! You'll find much better speed that way.

Using a generator approach like this could help you to avoid reading the whole file into memory. Open the input and output and write out processed data as you create it.

EDIT: fixed a couple bugs in my function

EDIT 2: I forgot about the flexibility of [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby). Here is an updated version of `group_by_newlines` that takes advantage of that to be a lot shorter (and probably less buggy).

```
from itertools import groupby

def group_by_newlines(lines):
    for key, group in groupby(lines, key=lambda line: bool(line.strip())):
        if key:  # True if the line isn't only whitespace
            yield list(group)  # the `group` is a generator yielding each of the lines
```

Comment: thanks, but still it doesn't solve the problem if  in between of first bunch and second bunch there are similer bunch but with different names and argument that I don't want to move them in new file with new format.
`
a: a
b: b

X: X
X: X

c: c
d: d `

and I am not interest on x:x to be moved in new file with different format, just want to skip it

Comment: I edited my post and shared a file link you can see there, like on that file, I want to take from first bunch and change it is format to other type which is declared in my post and look through out the file and if see the bunch with same names then moved, I mean by name is before the : sign after the : is the value